# Excel - Clickable link in pivot detail

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel pivot table with a SQL data source. One column of my data is the path and filename of an image. I'd like the user to be able to click to open the image when they are in the details view of the pivot data.

I tried to format the column like =Hyperlink("file://path/file", "Click to open") and it came through in the details but is not an Excel formula, it just looks like text. If I click that cell and then hit enter, it turns it into a formula and the link works.

Is there a better way to get a clickable link to an image in the details of the pivot table?